# Java variables starting with @ ("at" symbol)

Tags: java, enums, hashmap, naming-conventions

I have some variables in an **enum** that for some reason have to start with '@', for example:

```
public enum PR304MainDb {
    @MODE,
    @USERID,
    @ROLES,
    @MAX_DOC_COUNT
}
```

The way I use these variables is to put them in a **HashMap**...:

```
Map<String, Object> in = new HashMap<String, Object>();
in.put(PR304MainDb.@MODE.toString(), 5);
```

...and then use the HashMap as parameters when calling a **store procedure** (which code I can't change).

Also after the call I read the results and do some comparisons, like:

```
if (out.getKey().equals(PR304MainDb.@MAX_DOC_COUNT.toString())) {
//DO SOMETHING
}
```

**I know that these names are invalid**, but is there any alternative way to accomplish this?

Comment: You might want to consider whether a HashMap with enum keys is actually the right tool. I've answered the question anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a way - don't use the enum constant name (don't use `YOUR_CONSTANT.toString()` as the name).

Enums, like other classes, can have fields and methods. Some possibilities:

```
public enum PR304MainDb_Possibility1 {
    MODE("@MODE"),
    USERID("@USERID"),
    ROLES("@ROLES"),
    MAX_DOC_COUNT("@MAX_DOC_COUNT");

    private PR304MainDb_Possibility1(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public final String text;
}

public enum PR304MainDb_Possibility2 {
    MODE,
    USERID,
    ROLES,
    MAX_DOC_COUNT;

    public String getText() {return "@" + name();}
}
```

Comment: What's this name() function?

Comment: Returns the name of the enum constant, same as toString. The documentation says to use name when you want the exact name, and toString when you want something to display to a user. They must have a *reason* for saying that - maybe they'll change how toString works in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use @ in the symbol name, but what you can do is over-ride the toString method:

```
public enum PR304MainDb {
    MODE,
    USERID,
    ROLES,
    MAX_DOC_COUNT;


    @override
    String toString() {
        return "@"+super.toString();
    }
}
```

You can also do this not using the toString() method at all by defining a new method for the purpose, but that would involve changing the code that is using the enum.